# cannot execute function when subscribed to websocket

Tags: angular

In my project actually i am trying to make a whiteboard in which upon click of a function i subscribe to a web socket end point.

whenever i try to call the function "newDrawing()" inside the subscription..i am not able to so...

here is my ts code

```
  connect() {
    let socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/whiteBoard');
    this.ws = Stomp.over(socket);
    let that = this;
    this.ws.connect(
      {},
      function (frame) {
        that.ws.subscribe('/errors', function (message) {
          alert('Error ' + message.body);
        });
        that.ws.subscribe('/meeting/coordinates', function (message) {
          var res = JSON.parse(message.body);
          console.log(res);
          this.newDrawing(res.x, res.y);
        });
        that.disabled = true;
      },
      function (error) {
        alert('STOMP error ' + error);
      }
    );
  }

  newDrawing(x, y) {
    this.cx.moveTo(x, y); // from
    this.cx.lineTo(x, y);
    this.cx.stroke();
  }
```

i am shown with error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your connect method to :-

```
connect() {
    let socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/whiteBoard');
    this.ws = Stomp.over(socket);
    let that = this;
    this.ws.connect(
      {},
      (frame) => {
        that.ws.subscribe('/errors', (message) => {
          alert('Error ' + message.body);
        });
        that.ws.subscribe('/meeting/coordinates', (message) => {
          var res = JSON.parse(message.body);
          console.log(res);
          this.newDrawing(res.x, res.y);
        });
        that.disabled = true;
      },
      (error) => {
        alert('STOMP error ' + error);
      }
    );
  }
```